# Set date variable to last day of month 6 months from now Javascript

Tags: javascript

Instead of using the `AddDays(180)`, I'm trying to add 6 months and then set the day to the last day of that month.  i.e. `CustomDate8` should be `06/30/2015` at the end of the script.

```
//Set CustomDate8 to CustomDate5 + 6 Months
function Go(instance) {

var vehicle = instance;
var CustomDate5 = new Date('12/09/2014');
var CustomDate8 = new Date();

// update vehicle CustomDate5 field
if(vehicle.CustomDate5 != null)
{
vehicle.CustomDate8 = vehicle.CustomDate5.AddDays(180);
} 
if (!vehicle.CustomDate5)
{
vehicle.CustomDate8 = null;
}
}
```

I'm relatively new to javascript and appreciate the assistance.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as easy as adding 7 months, then setting the date to zero.

```js
var CustomDate5 = new Date('12/09/2014');
        
CustomDate5.setMonth( CustomDate5.getMonth() + 7 );
CustomDate5.setDate(0);

document.body.innerHTML = CustomDate5.toString();
```

As `1` is the first day in any month, setting it to `0` goes one day back, giving you the last day in the previous month.